# How does one go to a specific line with vs code with vim?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I thought it was surprising that `:` doesn't even seem to open the vim [last line mode](https://alvinalexander.com/linux/vim-vi-mode-editor-command-insert-mode) but when I do:

```
:10
```

nothing happens. Which I thought was weird. Anyone know how to make vs code go to a line using vim commands?

I am using: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim

---

Resources:

- related git issue: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1889
- reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/etfy37/how_does_one_go_to_a_specific_line_with_vs_code/

Comment: I'm using the same extension in vscode for linux and it's working, but another way to get to a line: while in command mode (esc) type the line number followed by a capital G.

Comment: @7iiBob how do I get in command mode? Is it just typing `:` in normal mode? Note I referenced I was having issues with that in vs code at the beginning of my question, but perhaps you meant something else.

Comment: To get into command mode with vim in vscode or just regular vim, you just type the esc key.

Comment: @7iiBob well that worked! How did you know how to do that? I've never seen that before. Does that work on normal vim?

Comment: The linked article uses non-standard mode names. We have Normal mode, Insert mode and Command(line)/Ex mode, typically.

Answer (score 3):

To get into command mode with vim in vscode or just regular vim, you simply type the esc key.

https://alvinalexander.com/linux/vim-vi-mode-editor-command-insert-mode

Comment: I meant last line mode. How does one get into that mode in vim + vs code?

Comment: You can only get into last line mode from command mode. Once you're in command mode with `esc`, then type `:` and you should see a colon appear at the bottom of the screen which you can type vim commands into.

Comment: The vscode version of vim isn't perfect, but all the main commands should work. One thing I do recommend is setting up a settings.json file which will allow you to customize vim in vscode to get the best of both worlds. Things like the standard ctrl-key vscode bindings can be kept while still using vim. Check out the quick example settings.json here: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim

Answer (score 2):

The exact commands that worked for me are in this order

1. First go to command mode by hitting the `ESC` key
2. Then type the line number `10`
3. Then `G`

Or while in command mode go to last line mode with `:`. The colon while appear at the bottom in the blue section of vs code:

[image]